# How to process deep update with subdocument in Mongodb/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use mongoose in this case. Let's say we have a Schema like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: { type: String, required: true },
    last: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
});
```

Let's say we already have document with first and last name. I need to update only first name and email with the following args object:

```
const updateUser = {
  name: {
    first: Eddy,
  },
  email: 'eddy@gordo.io'
};
```

If it will be used with mongoose update methods in most cases it would also change last name to `null`. That's because JavaScript doesn't support deep object merge and so on. So what's the best way to gain possibility to merge objects properly?

I've found the way to do it below but it doesn't seem to be the best solution:

```
User.findById(args.id, (error, user) => {
  if (error) throw err;
  user.name.first = args.name.first ? args.name.first : user.name.first;
  user.name.last = args.name.last ? args.name.last : user.name.last;
  user.email = args.email ? args.email : user.email;
  user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return updatedUser;
  });
});
```

I and Eslint don't like this with reassigning and unmaintainable code. Have somebody better idea? I'm not sure that I need to use lodash and other libs only for this capability.

Comment: See [Set Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) in the core documentation of the `$set` operator.

Comment: It's not the solution, what i've searching of. In this case we will have function like this `User.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id, { $set: { 'name.first': args.name.first, 'name.last': args.name.last, email: args.email } } )` or `User.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id, { $set: {name: args.name, email: args.email } } )`. I will forced to provide all args or user would be overwritten with null value or emit validation error when args is not provided. Thanks for your time, Neil!

Comment: No you will not `{ "$set": { "name.first": "Eddy", "email": "'eddy@gordo.io'" } }` will only modify the required fields. In fact, I'm sure I have an answer posted on here somewhere that converts the JavaScript object into the "dot notation" syntax. If I can only find it.

Comment: Here it is [Mongodb dot field update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26424321/2313887) or at least one of the posts. There might have been other variants, but that's the first one I could find.

Comment: I was seeking anything perfect fit for me about 3 days, still nothing. I was considering this approach but the cons are for User model as example that it's not invoking pre save hook with password crypting and other useful things for example. Thank you again, Neil!

Comment: I'll just add what I've said a couple of times even today. Doing `.find() -> "modify" -> .save()` is a really bad pattern which is prone to all sorts of problems. If you can `.update()` or `.find**Update()` in some variant, then do it. Schema hooks are convenient, but should not be relied on for scalability.

Comment: Totally agreed, that's because I'm trying to find something better. But at [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) it mentioned as a traditional approach with full-fledged validation. I think it need an issue at github, I'm sure its already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done with this issue.

Thanks to [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) with [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26424321/2313887).

We're need to map all object keys to dot.notation and pass to the $set.

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/VadimShvetsov/1bd8fdc9a3a0163f88f8aeb7923913f0) with this function. If we need two level nesting we can add another condition and mapping.

Anyway I hope that Mongoose API will resolve us to make deep merge with nested objects, but for now Neil's solution is the best in my opinion.